# Mutual Information and the informational coefficient of correlation

Tags: correlation, entropy, mutual-information

Linfoot (1957) introduced the informational coefficient of correlation, $\mathit{IC}$:

$$IC=\sqrt{1-e^{-2\cdot{I(X;Y)}}}$$

Where $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$ is the mutual information, the measure of the shared information between distributions $\mathit{X}$ and $\mathit{Y}$.  While $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$ is a metric, it has the limitation in not being bounded between 0 and 1 for practical use. Rather it is bounded between $\mathit{0≤I(X;Y)≤H(X,Y)}$.

A reported benefit of $\mathit{IC}$ is that, like the Pearson Correlation Coefficient, it is bounded between $\mathit{0≤IC≤1}$.  However, $\mathit{IC}$ is actually asymptotic to 1 from below.  At larger values of $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$, this is not a problem as - for all intent and purpose - $\mathit{IC}$ is equal to 1.  However, as $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$ tends towards zero, $\mathit{IC}$ becomes less than 1 even when the distributions are perfectly correlated.

Take the following example: we have a 3 x 3 matrix where both marginal distributions, $\mathit{H(X)}$ and $\mathit{H(Y)}$, are uniform. Hence, the following entropies apply:
$${H(X)=1.585}$$
$${H(Y)=1.585}$$
$${H(X,Y)=1.585}$$

and the mutual information is calculated as:
$${I(X;Y)=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)}$$
$${I(X;Y)=1.585+1.585-1.585}$$
$${I(X;Y)=1.585}$$

As $\mathit{H(X)= H(Y)=H(X,Y)}$, it is clear that all the information in $\mathit{X}$ is common with $\mathit{Y}$.  If the variables are quantified, rather than categorical, the Pearson Correlation Coefficient would, logically, be one.

Yet, in this above example, $\mathit{0≤IC≤1}$ is actually less than one as:
$$IC=\sqrt{1-e^{-2\cdot{1.585}}}=0.97877$$

It would seem possible one could make the informational coefficient of correlation, $\mathit{IC}$, be bounded between 0 and 1 through normalisation. This can be achieved by dividing by the joint entropy, which is the upbound entropy, such that:
$$\overline{IC}=\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-2\cdot{I(X;Y)}}}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-2\cdot{H(X,Y)}}}}$$

This would ensure $\mathit{0≤\overline{IC}≤1}$  $\forall$  $\mathit{I(X;Y)}$.

I trust I have got the above right. I have not seen any literature for the need for such a normalisation. My question is: Is such a normalisation reasonable and if not, why not? Are there any implications of such a normalisation?

Reference: Linfoot, E.H. (1957). An informational measure of correlation. Information and Control, 1, 85-89.

Comment: at the start its said that $IC$ is  bounded between $0$ and $1$ like correlation, so why are you trying to normalize it to these bounds when you already say it already is

Comment: @develarist - Please, I am not denying that $\mathit{IC}$ isn't bounded between 0 and 1 - that is obvious. My question relates to when one inserts real values that, in some circumstances, the maximum correlation is less than 1 (even when perfectly correlated). That is the core point of my question.

Comment: you mean, when Pearson's correlation ($\rho$) is clearly 1, like you're saying in your example, you are expecting the $IC$ to reach its maximum (1) as well? and in your example, you are assuming equal entropies should translate to $\rho=1$?